# AFTER DELETE trigger will not fire during a cascade delete

Tags: sql-server, trigger, foreign-key

I've got two tables, corresponding to `Nodes` in a graph and `Aisles` to which they *may* belong.  In addition, each `Aisle` has a `Node` at which it starts and ends.

`Aisle` Table:

```
Aisle char(4)
Start_Node int not null
End_Node int not null
...
```

This table *would* have foreign keys referencing the `Node` table (deleting on cascade), but this is apparently not possible (multiple cascade paths?) so I have to enforce this rule myself in a trigger on the `Node` Table...which looks like so:

```
Node_ID int
x float
y float
Aisle char(4) [MAY BE NULL]
```

Now, the trigger on the node table does some data integrity stuff, and I'm pretty sure a trigger is the right place to do it since I absolutely cannot think of a situation where I *wouldn't* want the trigger to fire -- but it doesn't always fire...

If I manually delete an entry from the `Aisle` table to which rows in `Node` reference, the deletion cascades to the `Node` table and the trigger definitely fires, as expected.

But if I delete a record from the `Node` table to which `Aisle` rows reference, the trigger on the Node table enforces the pseudo-foreign key constraint in `Aisle` (deleting rows in `Aisle` by design), which should then cascade the deletions back to `Node` and call the trigger *again* (by design), but I have verified multiple times that the trigger never gets called after the cascade occurs.

What's going on here?  I'm clearly missing some detail on how triggers and FKs interact...for the record, nested triggers are active, I'm using an After Delete trigger, and I'm definitely no DBA.

Comment: Considered an instead of delete trigger?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you wouldn't just use a foregin key on Aisle and CASCADE ON DELETE?  Are you doing something else in the trigger?